# node.js: bluebird alternative for async.whilst?

Tags: node.js, bluebird, async.js

I want to run a while loop which depends on a condition which is updated with each iteration. Now the challenge is that the code in each iteration is asynchronous.

One way to accomplish this by using async.whilst(). However, I am trying to look for an alternative using bluebird promises. Is there any such alternative available ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-bluebird
Has the same features of `async` but using bluebird.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ? **[.all() -> Promise](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise)**

```
var pendingPromises = [];
while (yourConditions) {
    pendingPromises.push(service.doSomethingAsync());
}
Promise.all(pendingPromises).then(function(result) {
    console.log("all the files were created", result);
});
```

Comment: This isn't a good pattern to follow because the request for help was that the condition is async. So the "doSomethingAsync()" method could be updating the condition of the "while" loop, which can't work in this example because `while` is sync. Also, `Promise.all()` would run all the async tasks concurrently, while they need to be run serially, so each one has a chance to update the condition before the next one starts.